# Semi prime numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory, prime-numbers

The high school textbook I am using has the example of semi-prime numbers.  They wanted students to find (by "perspiration")  all the semi-prime numbers less than $50$  (for a question on set theory).

A semi-prime number is the product of exactly two prime numbers (not necessarily distinct).

How would I generate the first $n$ semi-prime numbers using *Mathematica*?

Comment: Closely related: [Generating a list of cubefree numbers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37329/generating-a-list-of-cubefree-numbers)

Comment: As always, the help of this community is very much appreciated!  Thank you to everyone who responded.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `FactorInteger` to find out whether or not there are exactly two primes building up a number:

```
SemiPrimeQ[n_Integer] := With[{factors = FactorInteger[n]},
  Total[factors[[All, 2]]] == 2
  ]
```

The rest is easy:

```
Select[Range[50], SemiPrimeQ]
(* {4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 46, 49} *)
```

And for those who like inline anonymous functions

```
Select[Range[50], Total[Last /@ FactorInteger[#]] == 2 &]
(* {4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 46, 49} *)
```

### Update

If you want to create all semi primes which consist of primes smaller than the n-th prime, then this is a one-liner too. Here are all semi primes for the first 10 prime numbers:

```
Union[Times @@@ Tuples[Array[Prime, 10], 2]]
(* {4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, \
46, 49, 51, 55, 57, 58, 65, 69, 77, 85, 87, 91, 95, 115, 119, 121, \
133, 143, 145, 161, 169, 187, 203, 209, 221, 247, 253, 289, 299, 319, \
323, 361, 377, 391, 437, 493, 529, 551, 667, 841} *)
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast, and I appreciate that answer.  Makes sense to me!  I was messing around with lists of Primes and Tuples.  This does just what I wanted, THANK YOU,  I'll just wait a bit and see if there are other answers.

Comment: @TomDeVries, yes, waiting is always good, because people tend to look on *unaccepted* question to gain reputation. Many surprising answer can come up this way and you will see many different approaches.

Comment: @RunnyKine In fact... let me check.

Comment: @RunnyKine You have to check further ;-) The problem is that the last list is (due to Tuples) not sorted.

Comment: Ah, you're right. My mistake.

Comment: @RunnyKine But the list contained duplicates as well, so I wrapped a `Union` around it. Thanks for paying attention!

Comment: No worries :). +1

Answer (score 20):

The built-in function`PrimeOmega` gives you the number of prime factors and counts multiplicities. Therefore, this can easily be used to give you semi-primes as you have defined them:

```
With[{r = Range[50]}, Pick[r, PrimeOmega[r], 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks for that,  no idea about that function

Comment: Never mistake `PrimeOmega` with [`OmegaPrime`](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Omega_Prime)! +1

Comment: @halirutan  "Semi-Primes Assemble!"

Answer (score 8):

By using a pregenerated list of prime numbers:

```
lst = Prime[Range@PrimePi[25]];
Select[Union@Flatten[lst*# & /@ lst], # < 50 &]
(* {4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 46, 49} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun, here's an approach that uses `ReplaceList`:

```
With[{n = 50}, 
 Union @@ ReplaceList[
   Array[Prime, n], {pre___, y_, rest___} :> y {pre, y}]]

(* {4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 46, 49, 51, \
55, 57, 58, 65, 69, 77, 85, 87, 91, 95, 115, 119, 121, 133, 143, 145, \
161, 169, 187, 203, 209, 221, 247, 253, 289, 299, 319, 323, 361, 377, \
391, 437, 493, 529, 551, 667, 841} *)
```